# What token to obtain for cron job for creating posts in fb page using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron

I am an admin of a Facebook page. I want to create a Cron job for posting on the Facebook page using php sdk. I think I probably need some kind of offline access token or something like that is based on the Google's php sdk, but I don't have any idea how to do it. The current version of fb sdk I'm using is 5.6. So, I'm guessing the default access token is what I probably need, do I?

```
$fb = new Facebook([
  'app_id' => '...',
  'app_secret' => '...',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.11',
  //'default_access_token' => '{access-token}', // optional
]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an **Extended Page Token**. How to create that one is explained in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

**Create User Token > Extend User Token > Get Extended Page Token**

You need to create the User Token with the `publish_pages` and `manage_pages` permission to be able to post to the Page as admin.

Comment: do i have to review permission when i am the admin of the page and the app i am developing? As i am getting this error and i dont know why: `Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthorizationException: (#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission`

Comment: review is only neccessary if you want OTHER users to be able to use your app. you just need to authorize yourself with the correct permissions, no review needed.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. btw, i think those links u have provided are for older sdk of the php or maybe im mistaking?

Comment: the main content of both links is still valid, it´s just some pieces of example code. if you understand how it works, you don´t need that.

Comment: and it is ok to ask you to add in your answer that u dont need to valide `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` if you like to do a cron job like i do and u r the admin of the fb page and also the admin of the app u r using in fb to execute the code as this took me a while to understand.